# Standardize font size on an existing large website

Tags: html, css, sass

I am handling a large website with millions of users per day. The website has been a combined effort of multiple frontend developers over time and was developed without any style guide or proper design measurements. As a result each and every developer has given font sizes according to their likeness and almost every other tag has a font-style property defined in it's CSS/SCSS. I want to make the font size on the website standardized so that look and feel of all pages and components on the same page remains the same. What is the best and scalable approach we can use to do these font size changes and achieve the goal in limited amount of time?
Note - Company is not currently open to rewrite the code. So, the only route is modifying the existing code.

Comment: Make one class for each element you have(h1,...,h6, p, li, ul, span, div, etc.) and define one font size for each element, and then add class into every element. There is no easy way around it.

Comment: Define one class above all, and make sure to use `!important` tag to be sure you are overriding them, but there is no shortcut really.

Comment: They don't want to pay for a "good" job, they just want to pay for a "quick" job. 
Fine! Just use `* { font-size: 14px !important; }`

Comment: Pulling the above three answers together, one possible get-around would be to set each element's `font-size: [some value]rem !important`. I provided an [example](https://codepen.io/yd-han/pen/ZdPzmj?editors=1100).

Answer (score 0):

Leverage your code editor's global search/replace functionality. For example, let's say your existing styles use font sizes of `16px`, `17px`, `18px`, `19px`, `20px`. You want to narrow these down to two font sizes: `16px` and `20px`. Do a global search for each variant, and replace it with the size you want: `font-size: 17px` becomes `font-size: 16px`, etc.

If you need to do more complex searches, you can use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).